# android connect to internet event

Tags: android, events, connection

Is there an event that tells me that the device has connected to the INTERNET (3G or wifi)? I need to start some requests only after the device connects to the INTERNET. The code needs to support Android 2.1. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a Broadcast receiver and wait for the action `ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION`

Here the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)

Ex:

```
broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context
                            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);


                        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
                        //Play with the info about current network state


                    }

                }
            };

            intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
            intentFilter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
            registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
```

Comment: This is what I was searching for. Thanks.

Comment: is right see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767591/check-intent-internet-connection

Answer (score 2):

Use a Broadcast receiver which will get called whenever the network state changes:

```
private NetworkStateReceiver mNetSateReceiver = null;

private class NetworkStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent )
    {
        // Check the network state to determine whether
        // we're connected or disconnected
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    registerReceiver( mNetSateReceiver, new IntentFilter(
        ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION ) );
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    save();
    unregisterReceiver( mNetSateReceiver );
}
```

onReceive will get called whenever the network state changes, and you can use the techniques detailed in the other answer to determine whether you're actually connected or not.

Answer (score 1):

Using this function you are able to know device have internet connected of not:

```
public static boolean connectionCheck(final Context context)
{   
    boolean returnTemp=true;
    ConnectivityManager conManager = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo i = conManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if ((i == null)||(!i.isConnected())||(!i.isAvailable()))
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new Builder(context);
        dialog.setTitle("CONNECTION STATUS");
        dialog.setMessage("Failed");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setPositiveButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
        Toast.makeText(TennisAppActivity.mContext,"Wi-Fi On", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
        return false;
    }
    return true;`enter code here`
}
```

Comment: please see my comment above :(

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean checkInternetConnection(Context context) {

    final ConnectivityManager mConnectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    final NetworkInfo netInfo = mConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    } else
        return false;
}
```

Use this function, function will return true if internet is connected else false

Comment: I know how to check if device is connected to internet but I need to know when device connects to internet without making repeated checks