# Unity Ads connection error

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm having trouble with unity ads, when I open/test my game on an android device that is not connected to an internet, the button to watch an ad will not show and also, when I connect the phone to an internet without closing the game, the button still not gonna show. The only way to show the button is to restart or re-open the game.

What I want to do is when I connect the phone to an internet without closing the game, the button will appear/show. How am I suppose to do that?

Comment: try something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056231/android-connect-to-internet-event

Comment: I did use an Android Native Plugin to my game, but it still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this answer for checking is internet connection available: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/567497/how-to-100-check-internet-availability.html
Bellow correct answer you can find more simplified answer from  pixel_fiend. Then you could create a timer which is going to call method for checking the internet connection every few.seconds. If method returns false, timer will reset and call the method again after some time. If method returns true then stop the timer. You have internet connection and activate the button.