# How to detect whether network service state changed in android?

Tags: android

How to detect network service state changes in roaming?

```
     <N/wSate 1>     <N/wstate 2>
```

For Eg: India  -->    England    -->     China

Here how to detect n/w state change from 1 to 2??

Thanks,
Chitra

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767591/check-intent-internet-connection