# Prevent some code from being executed in program flow

Tags: java, android

In my onCreate method in main activity i have some code which is checking if wifi connection is enabled. If it isn't i'm trying to automatically enabled it (very important now ) **and after that** i want to make other stuff ( starting service ..and other things). Its very important that it must be enabled **before proceeding** with execution !

I already tried AsyncTask , but with no luck. (code is still executing down below, before task in AsyncTask is completed ).

How to achive that some code will execute **AFTER** certain task is completed?

EDIT:

my onCreate in main activity

```
wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE); 

    if(!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {


        new Asyn(this, progress, wifiManager);


        } 


    startService(new Intent(intentt));
```

Asyn Class

```
public class Asyn extends AsyncTask<Context, Integer, Long> {

private Context context;
private ProgressDialog pd;
private WifiManager wm;

   public Asyn(Context context, ProgressDialog pd, WifiManager wm) {
     this.context = context;
     this.pd = pd;
     this.wm = wm;
    }



@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();
    pd = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Enabling wifi");

}

@Override
protected Long doInBackground(Context... params) {

    wm.setWifiEnabled(true);


    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    pd.dismiss();

}
```

}

I dont want to execute "startService" until wifi is not fully enabled!

Comment: Show us your AsyncTask code and invocation. You probably get the order confused.

Comment: Right, so you did get the order confused. Happens. First off, you're not executing the AsyncTask -- you need to invoke `new Async().execute()` to fire it off. Lastly, you need to start your service in a Receiver for NetworkState. The system will notify you when Wifi becomes available, and THEN you start your service. It would probably be more elegant to have the Service itself listen to Network state and act accordingly.

Comment: ah my bad. i had .execute(), but i deleted it when i was doing something.. my bad. (i know because Async was executing )

Will try to put startservice onPostExecute.

Comment: Putting it in postExecute won't solve your problem. You actually don't even need the AsyncTask. `setWifiEnabled()` runs async, and the only way you know you have a Network connection is by setting a BroadcastReceiver to listen to Network changes and looking for the network connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Async task is not the solution since starting WIFI is something that you can't just assume will happen after you call `wm.setWifiEnabled(true);`
You'll have to add a Broadcast receiver on WiFi state.
Please have a look at this answer:

[Listening WIFI state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434235/android-i-want-to-set-listener-to-listen-on-wireless-state-can-anyone-help-me-w)

I believe the second answer, (not the one that was accepted) is what you seek