# Is there any way to know, change of wifi network in android?

Tags: android, wifi

I'm developing an app. Application restarts when wifi network is switched from netwok-1 to network-2. Problem is that I don't know to detect changing in wifi network. Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9463814/1283215

Comment: Thanks for replies. Hey guys, i'm asking for the indication of an access point change of the wifi network. So whats your suggestion??

Answer (score 0):

In general you don't have to take care of the which wifi network is connected, [ConnectivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html) will do it on your behalf.

```
ConnectivityManager cm =
     (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                      activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
```

Now if your app/device(s) changes network state, then you need to monitor the connectivity_change using some broadcast.

```
<action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
```

It'll help you to broadcast only when you've previously suspended updates or downloads in order to resume them.

This [tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-internet-connection-status-network-change/) will help you.