# when internet connection failed, then show text and repeat loop until connection available?

Tags: android, networking, android-webview

I show a website in a webview. I want now to show at first a blank screen with a logo at the top and a text "Checking Internet Connection". When the connection is available, then I show the website in a webview. 
Later when the internet connection failed, I want to show the same blank screen with the logo and the Text "Checking Internet Connection and trying to connect".

Comment: You aren't actually thinking of busy-waiting until the network becomes available, are you? That will kill the user's battery. You need to register a receiver for a connectivity change event. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767591/check-intent-internet-connection

Comment: Thanks to all. Receiver is, what i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before actually show the webview content, you can

`WebView.loadUrl (String url)`

the url can be local file in `/assets` folder, you can use a simple html which like your

> a blank screen with a logo at the top and a text "Checking Internet
>   Connection

updating:

step1 :check the internet, this is you can control

step2: try to load actually website,

`WebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(...))`

in your `WebViewClient` class , override method

`public void onReceivedError (WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)`

when receive error, you can `WebView.loadUrl(...)`

Comment: But when i in onReceivedError, i show the website, and thats it. This don't make a new connection check. Or is that so, that when i have a connection im going from onReceivedError to "public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading"?

Comment: ye, `onReceivedError` also show the http error page. can you try this: make a thread to request using `HttpClient.execute (HttpUriRequest request)` to check the response form server, if the response code is right( like 200 ),actually to load the url, otherwise load your custom html file?

Comment: Do not do it with the loop -- LOOP BAD!