# Start and stop broadcast receiver

Tags: android

I want to start and stop a broadcast receiver from two buttons.
I had written the code for this in two button listeners.

The code is as follows:-

In startButton I have written the code for registering receiver as follows

```
     startCallBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            startCallBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            stopCallBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            //register call receiver.
            registerReceiver(callReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            "android.intent.action.CALL"));
           System.out.println("Registered Call Receiver Perfectly");
        }
    });
```

In a stop button I have written the call for stop receiver as

```
   stopCallBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            stopCallBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            startCallBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SpeakOut.class));
            FileOutputStream fos;

          //Unregister sms receivers
            unregisterReceiver(callReceiver);
            System.out.println("Unregistered Call Broadcast Receiver");
        }
    });
```

still the listener is calling when new call is receiving

Comment: Did you put this receiver also in Manifest.xml?

Answer (score 12):

You can try this code for `enable` and `disable` `BroadcastReceiver`..I hope this will help you..

```
public void enableBroadcastReceiver(View view)
{

    ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(this, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled broadcast receiver", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
   /**
    * This method disables the Broadcast receiver registered in the AndroidManifest file.
    * @param view
    */
   public void disableBroadcastReceiver(View view){
    ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(this, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled broadcst receiver", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
```

Comment: why is it necessary the view attribute?

Answer (score 3):

in **manifest**

```
 <receiver android:name="your receiver name">
```

main  **Activity**

```
BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.w("Check", "Inside On Receiver");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(BROADCAST_ACTION);
        filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        registerReceiver(br, filter);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(br);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are calling `unregisterReceiver()` of same `receiver` object on which you have called `registerReceiver()`. If you are creating new object for same receiver before releasing it,  then, the old receiver object which is registered can't be unregistered anymore as you have allocated new memory block to it.

For example, do this:

```
MyBroadcastReceiver receiver = new MyBroadCastReceiver();
registerReceiver(receiver);
unregisterReceiver(receiver);

receiver = new MyBraodCastReceiver();
```