# In Android how to check the internet status continuous using any background services like ASync Task

Tags: android

In Android how to check the internet status continuous using any background services like A Sync Task.
hi all.
in my app i want to check my internet status all over the application, when internet changes i need to show a dialog box with some user friendly message. please help me out with this.

Comment: implement Broadcast Receiver that will let you know when internet goes off or on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should listen to Connectivity State Changes through a Broadcast Receiver.No Background Service is Required

[More On this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767591/check-intent-internet-connection)