# How to fix Android WebView that shows only a link and the android logo

Tags: android, webview

When loading a WebView in an Android App, it shows only a link to the page instead of the website contents next to the android logo on black background. After restarting the app, the content is loaded.

Java Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;
    private String baseUrl = "http://www.example.com";

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
        webView.setId(10001);
        webView.setBackgroundColor(0xFF000000);
        // webView.setScrollBarStyle(SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);

        final Activity activity = this;
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);

        hideProgressbarText(progressDialog);

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                progressDialog.show();
                progressDialog.setProgress(0);
                activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
                progressDialog.incrementProgressBy(progress);
                if (progress == 100 && progressDialog.isShowing())
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        // final ProgressBar progressBar= (ProgressBar)
        // findViewById(R.id.progressbar);

        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        if (settings != null) {
            settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            settings.setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.MEDIUM);
        }

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            webView.loadUrl(baseUrl);
        }

    }

    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (webView.isFocused() && webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    private void hideProgressbarText(ProgressDialog progressDialog) {
        int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            progressDialog.setProgressNumberFormat(null);
            progressDialog.setProgressPercentFormat(null);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        webView.saveState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    }

}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Problem is that not the content is displayed but the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like what you've got is the error page in case of e.g. `page_not_found` or `DNS_failure`. i.e. What you saw is the error messeage or the prompt text, which should be in `BLACK` color. However you just set your background color as `0xFF000000` (as same the text color) which will hide the prompt text.

Remove the `black` background and you may see the text. I suppose what's shown now is not your page content but some error prompt from webkit engine.

Comment: You are right. the problem occured if no internet connection was available. I solved it using this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767591/check-intent-internet-connection

Answer (score 0):

Use this Website for [webview](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/) reference they explained good manner

Make sure below

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: use two activity ,create button in 1st activity if you click the button it will redirect to second activity,maintain 2nd activity is webview activity,it will work