# CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE 5 seconds delay

Tags: android

I was [monitoring the changes on the network](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html#MonitorChanges) when I change from Wifi connection to Data. It takes around 3 seconds for the device to do that, but the `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` broadcast receiver got fired after the connection is back with more than a **5 seconds of delay** and that became around 8 seconds of total delay. I'm sure of that, I've write a ping script and have accurate measuring of that.

The question is if I have something that needs to be continued at the same second the connection is back. How to do that?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: although I doubt that this works always, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25305698/android-network-state-change-detection-takes-time