# Broadcasts are delayed

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

We use broadcasts to communicate state changes between a remote services and our UI. Doing this, we discovered a very strange behaviour: Sometimes (I can not find any clues why) these broadcasts are delayed around 8s.

How we send them (pretty basic, `mState` is just a enum) (Remote process in service):

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_STATE, mState);

Service.get().sendBroadcast(intent, null);
```

How the static receiver is registered (App):

```
<receiver android:name=".ServiceStateReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="service.intent.action.STATE_CHANGE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

The receiver class (App):

```
public class ServiceStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.v("State", "State via static received");
    }
}
```

This is now sometimes delayed (always for the same states)

State enum:

```
public enum State {
    DISCONNECTED,
    BT_DISABLED,
    BT_SCANNING,
    BT_TIMEOUT,
    BT_FAILURE,
    BT_LOCATION_NEEDED,
    CONNECTING,
    ACTIVATION_FAILURE,
    VIN_NEEDED,
    CAR_MODEL_NEEDED,
    MILEAGE_NEEDED,
    READY,
    IGNITION_OFF,
    IGNITION_ON;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name();
    }
}
```

Now comes the strange part: If I register a dynamic receiver we always receive ALL broadcasts immediately there. The static one still has that huge delay. If I send the broadcast via `sendOrderedBroadcast` BOTH (static & dynamic) have this delay.

Dynamic receiver:

```
registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Log.i("State", "State via dynamic received");
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(State.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED));
```

What I tried so far:

- send the broadcast from the main thread/a worker thread (nothing changed)
- played with the permission attribute (nothing changed)
- send the broadcast multiple times in a row (not changing anything, just getting multiple delayed broadcasts now)

Also: No output from logcat which seems related. Tried on different devices (OnePlus 3 7.1.1, Z3 6.0.1, S7 Edge 7.1.1), all show the same behaviour

I think this may be related: [Android network state change detection takes time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25305698/android-network-state-change-detection-takes-time)

Comment: There's also an issue at the Android Issue Tracker for it: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62298626

Answer (score 8):

After searching for a answer for hours, I found the? solution after posting this.

It seems like that adding the `FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND` flag to the intent completly removes this delay. Would be still nice to know why this happens and if this is a good "fix" or if I destroy something else with this.

This does the trick:

```
    intent.setFlags(FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND);
```

> If set, when sending a broadcast the recipient is allowed to run at
>   foreground priority, with a shorter timeout interval. During normal
>   broadcasts the receivers are not automatically hoisted out of the
>   background priority class.

Source: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND

Comment: did it actually helped reducing latency?