# Start another activity when detected network connection

Tags: java, android, eclipse, networking, android-studio

i am currently doing a project based on network connections.I am developing an app in which network connection is checked regularly.If there is no connection, a progress dialog should spin showing "No network connection" until the user himself turn the wifi on or any other kind of internet connection .After the wifi is turned on and if the app connects with wifi then the progress dialog should close and the control should pass to another activity. I have searched this in google for many times but didn't get a satisfactory answer. Below are my codes:

```
     public class Alert extends Activity implements Runnable{


        ProgressDialog pd;
     WifiManager wm,wifiManager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alert);


        wm = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);

        if(!wm.isWifiEnabled()) {
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Network Error!!", "Network not found.Please make sure there is presence of any kind of network connection!!");

        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();  
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();

        if(wm.isWifiEnabled()) {
            pd.dismiss();
     Intent in=new Intent(Alert.this,WebPageView.class);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            while(wm.getWifiState() != 3) {

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this using Handler, It may work.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alert);


        wm = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);

        Handler handler = new Handler();
     handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        if(!wm.isWifiEnabled()) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                if(pd == null)
                    pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Network Error!!", "Network not found.Please make sure there is presence of any kind of network connection!!");
                }
            });

        }else{
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                 if(pd != null)
                    pd.dismiss();
                 Intent in=new Intent(Alert.this,WebPageView.class);
                 startActivity(in); 
                }
            });


        }
        handler.postDelayed(this, 5000); //now is every 2 minutes
        }
     }, 5000);

    }
```

Comment: in the interval of 5 sec it crashes continuously and opens itself and again crashes as in a loop

Comment: I edited my answer can u plz check it and replay me.

Answer (score 1):

```
To check network connection, use ConnectivityManager class.
Add below method to your activity and call it to check network connection, if it returns true then it means network is available otherwise not.

private boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}

Now do it in your onCreate(...) method

if(!isNetworkAvailable(Alert.this)) {
    pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Network Error!!", "Network not found.Please make sure there is presence of any kind of network connection!!");
    Thread t = new Thread(this);
    t.start();  
}else{
    if(pd != null && pd.isShowing()){
        pd.dismiss();
    }
    Intent in=new Intent(Alert.this,WebPageView.class);
    startActivity(in);
}

Hope this will help you.
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767591/check-intent-internet-connection),

Depends on internet state change you can call your activity.

Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: Seems more like a comment than an answer

Comment: He is checking internet regularly wifi or some other network. Instant of that he can check internet state. This is right way to check internet state. then he can call specific activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
  @Override
 public void run() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    while(running) {

        try {
  ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)
   context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null) {
            if (info.isConnected()) {
                // you got a connection! tell your user!
                Log.i("Post", "Connected");
                running=false;
   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

      @Override
       public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     pd.dismiss();
      }
        });
                Intent intent_service=new Intent(this, anotherActivity.class);
                context.startService(intent_service);

            }

        } 
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this class in your project:

```
public class Utility {
    public static boolean isNetworkConnected(Context context){
        boolean connected = false;
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        connected = (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null&&cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable() && cm
            .getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected());
        return connected;
    }
    public static void showAlert(final Activity activity, final String message,final String title) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        builder.setMessage(message).setTitle(title).setCancelable(false)
            .setNegativeButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id){
                    dialog.cancel();
                    activity.finish();
                }
            });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
    public static void showAlertValidation(final Activity activity,final String message,final String title){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        builder.setMessage(message).setTitle(title).setCancelable(false)
            .setNegativeButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id){
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
}
```

This class detects if your internet connection is on or not. After that in your activity, put the following code:

```
    if(Utility.isNetworkConnected(Alert.this))
    {
Intent in=new Intent(Alert.this,WebPageView.class);
            startActivity(in);
}
            else if(!Utility.isNetworkConnected(Alert.this))
                Utility.showAlert(Alert.this,"Internet Connection Not Present.","Network Error!");
```

Check and see if your problem is solved or not.