# WebView with custom error Message Android

Tags: android, webview

Hi guys i have created a WebView with custom error message but i am not able to run it can you guys guide me where i am going wrong

MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.content.Context;

import android.widget.TextView;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 private WebView nWebView;
 float m_downX = 0;
 WebView view;
 ProgressBar progressBar;
 TextView txtview;
 public Context context;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     nWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
     nWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
     nWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/");
     nWebView.setWebViewClient(new uosWebViewClient());
     nWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
     nWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);


     ConnectivityDetector cd = new ConnectivityDetector(context);
     Boolean isConnected = cd.isConnectedToInternet();

     if (isConnected){
         //do nothing
     } else {
         nWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         txtview.setText("Please connect to Internet");
         txtview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     }


     nWebView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
         public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {


             switch (event.getAction()) {
                 case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                     // save the x
                     m_downX = event.getX();
                 }
                 break;

                 case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                 case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                 case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                     // set x so that it doesn't move
                     event.setLocation(m_downX, event.getY());
                 }
                 break;

             }

             return false;
         }
     });

 }

 private class uosWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

     @Override
     public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String url) {
         webview.loadUrl(url);
     return true;
 }

     @Override
     public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
         super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
     }

     @Override
     public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
         super.onPageFinished(view, url);

     }
 }
 @Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && nWebView.canGoBack()) {
         nWebView.goBack();
         return true;
     }
     return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }

 }
```

ConectivityDetector

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class ConnectivityDetector extends MainActivity {
private Context ctxt;

public ConnectivityDetector(Context context) {
    this.ctxt = context;
}

public boolean isConnectedToInternet() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) ctxt.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivityManager != null) {
        NetworkInfo[] infos = connectivityManager.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (infos != null)
            for (int i = 0; i < infos.length; i++)
                if (infos[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    return true;
                }
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:visibility="gone" />

<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/webView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

I have given both the internet permissions and also Acess network state permission

Error Messages

```
 enter code here03-13 11:06:55.775    1215-1215/com.just_like.just_like I/Process﹕ Sending      signal. PID: 1215 SIG: 9
    03-13 11:08:12.475    1296-1296/com.just_like.just_like V/WebViewChromium﹕  Binding Chromium to the background looper Looper (main, tid 1) {b3d19d38}
    03-13 11:08:12.485    1296-1296/com.just_like.just_like I/chromium﹕  [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(112)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default  verbosity = 0
    03-13 11:08:12.495    1296-1296/com.just_like.just_like I/BrowserProcessMain﹕ Initializing chromium process, renderers=0
    03-13 11:08:12.575    1296-1296/com.just_like.just_like E/chromium﹕ [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(153)] No suitable EGL configs found.
    03-13 11:08:12.575    1296-1296/com.just_like.just_like E/chromium﹕ [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(620)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
    03-13 11:08:12.575    1296-1296/com.just_like.just_like E/chromium﹕ [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(153)] No suitable EGL configs found.
    03-13 11:08:12.575    1296-1296/com.just_like.just_like E/chromium﹕ [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(620)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
    03-13 11:08:12.585    1296-1296/com.just_like.just_like E/chromium﹕ [ERROR:gpu_info_collector.cc(86)] gfx::GLSurface::InitializeOneOff() failed
    03-13 11:08:12.615    1296-1315/com.just_like.just_like W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(888)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
    03-13 11:08:12.725    1296-1296/com.just_like.just_like D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 88K, 6% free 2895K/3060K, paused 66ms, total 67ms
    03-13 11:08:12.725    1296-1296/com.just_like.just_like I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 3.506MB for 635812-byte allocation
    03-13 11:08:12.815    1296-1320/com.just_like.just_like D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 5% free 3516K/3684K, paused 86ms, total 86ms
    03-13 11:08:12.985    1296-1296/com.just_like.just_like D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
    03-13 11:08:12.985    1296-1296/com.just_like.just_like W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a56ba8)
    03-13 11:08:12.995    1296-1296/com.just_like.just_like E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.just_like.just_like, PID: 1296
     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  ComponentInfo{com.just_like.just_like/com.just_like.just_like.MainActivity}:   java.lang.NullPointerException
            at  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)



    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)

    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at  com.just_like.just_like.ConnectivityDetector.isConnectedToInternet(ConnectivityDetector.java:16)
                at com.just_like.just_like.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
                                                                                              
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
                at    android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)

     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)

          at    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

    at com.just_like.just_like.ConnectivityDetector.isConnectedToInternet(ConnectivityDetector.java:16)

    at com.just_like.just_like.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)

    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)

     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            

        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
         
          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
          
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
```

Comment: Do you get an exception?

Comment: Yes i get  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.just_like.just_like, PID: 1296

Comment: Can you add the whole stack please?

Comment: The whole stack of Error messages its Too long to fit in Comment

Comment: Edit your question and add it there :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because when you initiated the `ConnectivityDetector cd = new ConnectivityDetector(context);` the context was null. 
Try the adding `context = this` before that line.

Comment: edited my answer. Sorry I thought you were calling it from within a fragment

Comment: Thank you bro now the app launches but my intent was that whenever their is no Internet on your phone the App displays a Custom Message but when i turn off my internet it says Unfortunately the app has stopped working

Comment: If you want to continuously monitor the internet connection you need to something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767591/check-intent-internet-connection

Comment: not continuously monitoring whenever the app opens it should just check for internet and when internet is available it should open the app or else display a custom message like Internet is not available something like that