# Android: check internet access continuously

Tags: android, connection, android-internet

Besides this:

```
InetAddress.getByName("www.xy.com").isReachable(timeout)
```

or pinging to any server

is there any other way to **continuously** check if the device has internet access. And by that I mean **not just connected** to any network, but having **actual access to the internet**.

Something similar to what **lollipop** does when it's connected to some WIFI network but the WIFI network does not have internet access and shows an **exclamation mark**.

**Note:**
I already know the below stuff and the connection change is detected fine

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
    isConnected = true;
    networkName = netInfo.getTypeName();
    networkType = netInfo.getType();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a broadcast to know the connectivity state. You can get more info in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767591/check-intent-internet-connection)

Answer (score 0):

To your Manifest File add these :

```
<receiver android:name=".YOURRECEIVERNAME">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Then Create java class like below:

```
public class YOURRECEIVERNAME extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "NetworkStateReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Network connectivity change");

        if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
            final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            final NetworkInfo ni = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

            if (ni != null && ni.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Network " + ni.getTypeName() + " connected");
            } else if (intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, Boolean.FALSE)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "There's no network connectivity");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now manually switch on and off network to see effect.