# Notify user when Internet connection is lost in android

Tags: android

I am trying to make an app where I need to notify the user via a toast when the connection to the internet is lost(either mobile data or wifi) and possibly launch another activity and return back to the main activity as soon as the user is back online.
Can someone please guide me in doing this.
Thank you.

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33584746/show-toast-when-there-is-no-internet-access-android

Answer (score 2):

Use NetworRequestCallBack provided by the Android to get the Internet connection changes. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback

```
    val connectivityManager = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    val networkRequest = NetworkRequest.Builder().build()
    connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(networkRequest, object :
        ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {

        override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
            super.onAvailable(network)
            // "Net connected"
        }

        override fun onLost(network: Network) {
            super.onLost(network)
            // "Network lost"
        }


        
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to check if network is available

```
   public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context activity) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
            = (ConnectivityManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

Use the above method as

```
  if(isNetworkAvailable(context)){
     //Network is available}
  else {
     //Network Unavailable
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but this is only working once but I need to notify user as many times the network is disconnected

Comment: You can do call this method everytime the user touches any part of your app. This way everytime before doing any task you can notify the users

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you want to achieve can be achieved seamlessly using [Reactive Network](https://github.com/pwittchen/ReactiveNetwork) library. If you already use RxJava in your project then it is even more convenient!

Here it is documented how you can observe network connectivity https://github.com/pwittchen/ReactiveNetwork#observing-network-connectivity