# Flexible Alarm Manager

Tags: android, network-programming, alarmmanager

first of all I would like to say sorry if the title is a bit misleading, I wasn't quite sure how to ask a question. :D

Let's say I start a repeating Alarm whos job is to get something of the internet (download a picture for example) every XY min (let say an hour).

So it would run for example at 1pm, 2pm, 3pm, ...

My question is this:

If user doesn't have internet connection at 2pm, alarm will try to get a picture > fail > try again at 3pm.

Is it possible to make so that it runs next time user connects to internet, rather than to wait another hour?

So, if the user connects to internet at 2:10pm, it should do the 2pm task again than, and not to wait till 3pm.

I hope you understand my question and can point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell android to let you know when the device's connectivity state changes (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767591/check-intent-internet-connection)).

So if the task couldn't execute at 2pm due to connectivity issues, you can try again once the device is connected to the Internet.