# Android deferred web request

Tags: android, okhttp

What is the best way to make a deferred simple okhttp3 web request like:

```
Request request = Request.Builder().url(url).post(body).build();
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

that gets executed as soon as a client goes online and only then to handle result?

For example, client makes change to the data locally and this change should be posted on server. But there are cases when user does it offline, but we still have to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a broadcast receiver which listen for internet [connectivity changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767591/check-intent-internet-connection), and Deferred library for deferring the request [Jdeferred](http://jdeferred.org/).

If use of deferred is too much work and overkill, You can use a conutdownlatch and 
wait on separate thread until, the connectivity change, but the wait time can be huge, so chose wisely.

You can also consider [CompletableFuture](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html). But this is available from api 24 only

Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: What if the app gets closed? Will this request be executed on next open?

Comment: nope, in that case persist your request in db or some file, when the app reopens look for these request in your application class and schedule them  again