# Alternative for alarm manager for periodic background tasks

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager, android-alarms, repeatingalarm

I need to allow user to use my app even if network is not available and make server calls when network is available. I am using alarm manager-broadcast receiver- service pattern. I periodically retry to make api calls. I also added the boot receiver. But when user kills the app using  overview screen, the alarms are not triggered again. Is there a better way to implement this common scenario?

Comment: Maybe this would help http://stackoverflow.com/a/3767766/6272369

Comment: I think you implemented alarms incorrectly. It should run scheduled tasks regardless of whether app has been killed, or not

Comment: @Vlad When you goto overview and swipe away the app, alarms of that app are cleared.

Answer (score 2):

You may use:- 
1. [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html)
2. [SyncAdapter](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html)

These will help you in case of periodically retry to make API calls