# How to schedule a task in android which will run on immediately after internet is available and reschedule it if fails?

Tags: java, android, gcm-network-manager

Need scheduler to

- `Run task immediately after net is available`
- `Reschedule task if it fails because of some problems.`
- `should handle cases of broadcast receiver to know if connection available`
- `No delay in execution if the internet is already available not like GCMNetworkManager's OneOfTask which take at least 30 seconds to execute the scheduled task`

I tried [GCM Network Manager's OneOfTask](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/OneoffTask) which handles it but takes at least 30 seconds to execute even if the internet is available.

Is there any other scheduler which will all above task in one.

Comment: I think you can use a BroadcastReceiver to listen for when network becomes available

Comment: _BroadcastReceiver_ will do your work.

Comment: Hello, wanted to not handle internet status check by own. It should be handled by scheduler itself

Answer (score 1):

Use a broadcast receiver which can listen to network connectivity change. And check weather the device is connected to internet or not using ConnectivityManager. If your device is connected to the internet then schedule your task.

To use broadcast receiver. Add the following lines to manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<receiver android:name="yourpackage.ConnectivityReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Listener class:

```
package yourpackage;

public class ConnectivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     final String action = intent.getAction();
     switch (action) {
        case ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION:

            ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                //start schedule 
            }else{
                //stop schedule 
            }
            break;
    }
}}
```

Comment: hey, here we are manually handling internet connectivity case, wherein scheduler itself should handle this case. OneOfTask

Comment: Anyway use Brodcast receiver to listen status of internet connection and do your task inside onReceive function. @GopinathLangote

Comment: I don't want myslef to run my task, schedular should take care of executing amit and handle the all senarios

Comment: So you dont want to use Broadcast receiver ? It is easy to use broadcast receiver to know wheather your application is connected to the internet or not? And it is also possible to make your app independent of activity only run particular task if the network status is changed.

Comment: yes it is easy. but schedular itself takes care about habdling network issues and rescheduling it if fails.

Comment: I guess your question is too broad and not specific.

Comment: yes in some sort and modified also. thanks for suggestion

Comment: By the way have you got the solution ?If so update your question .

Comment: not yet. still struggling to find they way that any android schedular handles it or not. still trying to make question more specific

Comment: Take a look https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to set a "Broadcast" once your device get internet off or on then a receiver will send callback to you then you can schedule task there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BroadcastReceiver to listen network status and if network is available then start a scheduler.
for scheduler you can user ScheduledExecutorService.
for example..

Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleWithFixedDelay(new     Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                 // call tast here
                }
            }, 0, 10, IntervalTime);

Answer (score 0):

1. No need to use Service
2. By using broadcast also u can do it.
3. when broadcast receive the status of internet then you can check the status and do your further .
4. hope it helpful for you if not then please let me know i will give the code. with proper explanation.

[Please click here check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767591/check-intent-internet-connection)

Comment: In that case you have to handle rescheduling task scenario by your own. where scheduler handles it.