# Android: Send Data to Server

Tags: android, sqlite

I am very new to android. I want to send data(location coordinates) from sql lite database to the server when connection is on.If the connection is off I have to store them in database. Do I need to have service on the background that sends the data to server when connection is on?

Comment: you don't have to, but you may. All depends on your choice. What is the question?

Comment: So the real question is how to detect if you're connected to the internet and when not? There are plenty of tutorials for this on SO an on other sites. [Check for internet connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-times-out) and [the event for internet connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767591/check-intent-internet-connection)

Comment: question is that Do I need the service on the background or not?

Comment: It depends on your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While submitting the form data check if internet is connected if yes send your data to server and if no save it in your database.
You need a broadcast receiver which will inform your when internet connection is connected, if connected call a service which will send data to the server and once send delete that data from database.

Comment: Thanks for telling the steps for it, do you mind adding some reference links on how to do these steps. This would help the OP.

Comment: Thanks I got it now